# Updating price in Ruby on Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm currently working on a project for an online application for booking space. Users can make enquiries and the owners of the space may accept/reject or even make a counter offer in the message thread.

Our application seems to update the term `(self.hire_to.to_date - self.hire_from.to_date).to_i`:

```
class EnquiryOffer < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :enquiry
  has_one :enquiry_state

  validates_presence_of :hire_from, :allow_blank => false
  validates_presence_of :hire_to, :allow_blank => false

  before_save do
    EnquiryOffer.where(enquiry_id: self.enquiry_id).update_all(:state => 'inactive')
  end

  def term
    Rails.logger.info "#### Active offer term #{(self.hire_to.to_date - self.hire_from.to_date).to_i}"
    (self.hire_to.to_date - self.hire_from.to_date).to_i
  end
end
```

What seems to be an issue is when a counter offer is made, the price is not updated. I'm guessing if I include the price in this model it should update when a new counter offer is made.

Am I right? (probably not!)

UPDATE:

enquiry model holds these pieces of code that should give you a better idea:

```
  def offer_price
    puts "price #{self.property.price}"
    puts "term #{self.active_offer.term}"
    self.property.price * self.active_offer.term
  end

def make_offer(conversation_id, offer_id)
    states.create! state: "offer_made", conversation_id: conversation_id, enquiry_offer_id: offer_id, receiver_id: self.user_id if open? || offer_rejected? || enquiry_rejected?
  end

  def active_offer
    Rails.logger.info "ACTIVE OFFER #{self.enquiry_offers.where("state = 'active'").first.inspect}"
    self.enquiry_offers.where("state = 'active'").first
  end

          html += action_view.render(:partial => 'messages/message_default', :locals => {:@message => "<h2><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-transfer'></i> You suggested a counter offer</h2> From <b>#{s.enquiry_offer.hire_from.strftime("%d/%m/%y")}</b> to <b>#{s.enquiry_offer.hire_to.strftime("%d/%m/%y")}</b> for <b>&pound;#{self.price.round}</b> with a fee of <b>&pound;#{self.commission(current_user)}</b>.", :@state => s, :@conversation => conversation, :@enquiry => self, :@url => Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.accept_offer_enquiries_path})
        elsif s.state == Enquiry::STATES[4]
          action_view = ActionView::Base.new(Rails.configuration.paths["app/views"])
          action_view.class_eval do 
            include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
            include ApplicationHelper
            def protect_against_forgery?
              false
            end
          end
```

The key issue is when making a counter offer the price stays the same as the initial offer that opened up the enquiry.

Comment: This is not enough information to go off of. What are you trying to do? How is a counter offer made? What are the relationships? Where is price? So many questions without answers please try and change the question to what you need to do and what is not working along with the appropriate code so we can help determine an answer.

Comment: In Rails 4 it's preferable to use `validates :x, presence: true` rather than the old-school `validates_presence_of` method.

Comment: I've added some extra code, which I hope will give you a better idea of where It's going wrong. Apologies for the long scroll bar!